# Handling specific URLs with intent filters in Xamarin Mono for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I'm attempting to have my Activity handle urls taking the form of `mydomain.com` or `www.mydomain.com` with both `http` and `https` schemes. Currently the IntentFilter attribute for my activity looks like this:

```
[IntentFilter(
  new[] { Intent.ActionView },
  Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
  DataHost = "mydomain.com",
  DataScheme = "http"
)]
```

Which generates this in the manifest, and doesn't appear to be working for any of the required url configurations:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="mydomain.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

**How can I change this attribute so that my activity will handle all urls of the form http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compressed single IntentFilter:

```
[
    IntentFilter
    (
        new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
            {
                Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Intent.CategoryBrowsable
            },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "http", "https" },
        DataHosts = new[] { "*.xamarin.com", "xamarin.com" },
        DataMimeType = "text/plain"
    )
]
```

will generate following AndroidManifest.xml node:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <data android:host="*.xamarin.com" />
    <data android:host="xamarin.com" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple intent filter attributes

```
[IntentFilter(
  new[] { Intent.ActionView },
  Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
  DataHost = "mydomain.com",
  DataScheme = "http"
)]
[IntentFilter(
  new[] { Intent.ActionView },
  Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
  DataHost = "mydomain.com",
  DataScheme = "https"
)]
[IntentFilter(
  new[] { Intent.ActionView },
  Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
  DataHost = "*.mydomain.com",
  DataScheme = "http"
)]
[IntentFilter(
  new[] { Intent.ActionView },
  Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
  DataHost = "*.mydomain.com",
  DataScheme = "https"
)]
public class MyActivity : Activity {}
```

the resulting xml will be

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="mydomain.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="mydomain.com" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="*.mydomain.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="*.mydomain.com" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Would I need another two instances of IntentFilter attribute in order to append the 'www' alias for both schemes?

Comment: You can use wildcards for subdomains without adding additional intent filters.

Comment: It would be nice if you appended an example of a wildcard usage into your answer.

Comment: Do I get it right that the wildcard `*.mydomain.com` does not cover the second-tier domain itself i.e. `mydomain.com`?

Comment: it's much better this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933883/4183499) instead of duplicate attributes.

Comment: @ZverevEvgeniy, yes you are right. The subdomains of a site are different than the domain itself.

Comment: Android 11 adds the visibility feature that requires a `<queries>` element in the manifest. Is it possible to define that in code using an attribute instead of directly in the manifest?